# Grafana RAG Status different thresholds for Amber and Green from Prometheus Datasource

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I am using a "singlestat" Grafana visualisation to create a RAG status from the following query:

`sum(up{container_name="my-application",environment_name="$env"})`

[image]

So this will tally up the number of running containers in say the production environment. The following visualisation gives a RAG status panel that is RED on zero containers found, AMBER on one container and GREEN on two or more.

[image: Grafana Query Visualisation]

So far so good but in other environments like development the number of containers running for "my-application" is only one so RAG status is always reported as AMBER.

How do I handle this? I can't see a way of configuring the "singlestat" visualisation so should I manipulate the returned value from the query and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was to modify the query and falsely inflate the returned value for environments that are not running the production minimum of two containers.

```
(
   sum(up{container_name="my-container", environment_name=~"dev|integration", environment_name="$env"}) + 1 
   AND
   (sum(up{container_name="my-container", environment_name=~"dev|integration", environment_name="$env"} == 1)
)
OR
sum(up{container_name="my-container", environment_name=~"dev|integration", environment_name="$env"}) != 1
OR
sum(up{container_name="my-container", environment_name="prod", environment_name="$env"})
OR
on() vector(0)
```

Answer from here: [PromQL if then statement equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66493087/promql-if-then-statement-equivalent)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `avg(up{container_name="my-application",environment_name="$env"})`. If it returns 1, then all the containers are live. If it returns value lower than 1, then something is wrong. The returned value can be multiplied by 100 and interpreted as the percentage of healthy containers.

Comment: I did actually start off using "avg" like this but after a few minutes the average will become 1 (1x100) again (in environments with more that 1 container) and the RAG status will return to GREEN (Threshold set to 50,100) even when the container count is still down by one.