# PromQL if then statement equivalent

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have a simple PromQL query that performs a count:

```
sum(up{container_name="my-container",environment_name="$env"})
```

This is part of a Grafana Dashboard and allows for ${env} to be selected from a drop down menu.

I would like to perform different queries depending on the environment.

How do I construct something like this in PromQL:

```
if ${env} == 'dev' or ${env} == 'integration':
  if sum(up{container_name="my-container",environment_name="$env"}) == 1:
    sum(up{container_name="my-container",environment_name="$env"}) + 1
  else:
    sum(up{container_name="my-container",environment_name="$env"})
else:
  sum(up{container_name="my-container",environment_name="$env"})
```

The purpose is to falsely inflate the count to trigger a healthy threshold in a RAG status panel in environments that are running single containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query like this:

```
(
   sum(up{container_name="my-container", environment_name=~"dev|integration", environment_name="$env"}) + 1 
   AND
   (sum(up{container_name="my-container", environment_name=~"dev|integration", environment_name="$env"} == 1)
)
OR
sum(up{container_name="my-container", environment_name=~"dev|integration", environment_name="$env"}) != 1
OR
sum(up{container_name="my-container", environment_name="prod", environment_name="$env"})
OR
on() vector(0)
```

this will return the amount of instances increased by one when the amount of instances is 1 (thats what the `and` does) and the user selected the dev or integration environment.
The `or` would al three metrics at once, but due to the query and the users selection, there can be only one metric that is returned.

Comment: Thats really interesting - is this "~" a contains special character? It seems to throw a parse error in Grafana.

Comment: sorry, I just fixed it. the operator is "=~" and not "~=". it means matches the regex

Comment: Please don't apologies, without a data set to test against it is so difficult  Your help has been invaluable and allowed me to get a query working but I have a couple of questions. env= should read environment_name as $env is a Grafana variable so can not be used in a PromQL (sorry I was not clear on this). Line 7 is missing some detail at the start (I assume up{container_name="my-container",).  Also what is the purpose of line 7? Finally last line needed to have sum added for multiple returns on up but is this the only place sum is required, maybe line 7 as well?

Comment: line 7 is missing the container_name selector, thats true, fixing that. its purpose its the else part of the first 2 lines so creating a metric when the first one does not (because its value is not 1), so it might be 0 or 2 and more.

Comment: if you have an env variable declared in grafana, you can declare use $env  in your queries referencing its value

Comment: Very insightful comments, thank you. I have had a chance to make some minor tweaks that handle issues I discovered in relation to multiple result returns in a time period. I will add them as an edit to your excellent answer.

Comment: yeps, I guess tehre might be still and mistake in it. Its difficult if you cannot test the queries and see if they return the expected results

Comment: I unfortunately can not add my edit as the "edit queue is full" but the change I was going to make was  env="$env" to environment_name="$env". I also wrapped each query in sum().